# FIREBASE ERROR While deleting Custom Remote Model : "Remote model does not support listing downloaded models"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to get list of all Custom ML models downloaded from Firebase and delete all other model except the current and latest model in my app, so that the users memory is not wasted.

```
private fun deleteOldModels(
    firebaseManager: FirebaseModelManager,
    currentModel: FirebaseCustomRemoteModel
) {
  firebaseManager.getDownloadedModels(FirebaseCustomRemoteModel::class.java)
    .addOnSuccessListener { models->
        for(model in models){
            if (model.modelName != currentModel.modelName) {
                firebaseManager.deleteDownloadedModel(model)
            }
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d(DOWNLOAD_TAG, "deleteOldModels: FAILED ${it.message}")
    }
}
```

Any advice regarding this or any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately listing custom model is not implemented. I believe it only works for download translation models. There's currently no way to list downloaded models.